# why anchor links dynamically generated by data-binding won't jump to the targeted id when clicked

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, hyperlink, anchor

I'm working on an Angular 10 project (asp.net + angular TS), in which a FAQ text document requires using internal links for easily locating specific content. the document data is rendered from db with a data structure like
{
"Id": 1,
"Name": "Term",
"Order": 1,
"Heading": "General",
"Content": "How can I give an Account Name"
}, ...

In order to quickly jump to the specific document content, I created anchor links as below in html

```html
<div class="row"> 
        <section style="overflow: auto;">            
            <div>
                <ol class="heading" *ngFor="let document of documents">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#{{document.heading}}">{{document.heading}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <hr>
                <ol class="content" *ngFor="let document of documents">
                    <li>
                        <h3 id="{{document.heading}}">{{document.heading}}</h3>
                        [text]="document.content"
                    </li>
                </ol>              
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, clicking these anchor links generated from data-binding won't jump to the targeted content part but hanging at home page with url, e.g., "https://localhost:4200/#How%20can%20I%20give%20an%20Account%20Name", when a heading "How can I give an Account Name" was clicked.

The url looks like the anchor link can be correctly created by binding document data. but why does not it lead to the content part but home page? Please kindly help!

Comment: You want something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcwjln?file=src/app/app.component.html)?

Comment: confirm @Eldar link works

Comment: @Eldar, thanks for the working demo. I can't see the diff in essence. I encountered the same issue when run your demo code within my project. Is there a possibility that the internal links got blocked somewhere?

Comment: Nope, the only thing possible is you explicitly set `HashLocationStrategy` so your router tries to route somewhere when you click those.